# Make all dropdowns of a Bootstrap nav display at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap nav bar and I have 5 li elements with a dropdown ul with many sub elements.

I want to make them all display at the same time when you click on any of the category titles to display the dropdown menu. So if the first li is clicked I want all the rest of the dropdowns to toggle as well.

This would be a sample of my code and I would like both ul with a dropown menu class to show when any of the li class dropdown is cicked:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category A</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category B</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add screenshots of what you are expecting

Comment: Added an answer for you. Hope its what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you. It is a overwriting bootstrap event on the dropdown to use your own custom code. You actually just capture the `on('click')` of the `.nav li.dropdown` and then loop through all the dropdowns to toggle the open class that bootstrap uses.

Here is a sample code to help.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ZJyBpw

Hope this is the solution your looking for.